# Update table column based on another table based on ID

Tags: sql, db2

I have 2 tables 'table1' and 'table2'.
`table1` has 10,000 records and `table2` has 5,000 records. 
Both tables have "RECORD_ID" column. All RECORD_ID's that are in `table2` can be found in `table1`.

I want to UPDATE the "PRICE" column of `table1` based on the "RECORD_ID" column of `table2`.

```
update  table1 set PRICE = table2.PRICE where RECORD_ID = table2.RECORD_ID
```

I got this error message:

> SQL0206N "table2.PRICE" is not valid in the context where it is used
>   SQLSTATE=42703

I am using DB2.

Comment: you have to use join

Comment: join doesnt work for db2

Comment: of course join DOES WORK for db2

Comment: Not for update on iseries

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
UPDATE table1 f1 
SET f1.price =(
                SELECT f2.price 
                FROM table2 f2 
                WHERE f2.record_id = f1.record_id
              )
WHERE exists
(
   SELECT f2.price 
   FROM table2 f2 
   WHERE f2.record_id = f1.record_id
)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
UPDATE table1 SET table1.price = (SELECT table2.price FROM table2 WHERE table2.record_id = table1.record_id)
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to use a join like this:

```
UPDATE
Table1
SET
Table1.Column = T2.Column
FROM
Table1 T1
INNER JOIN
Table2 T2
ON 
T1.PK = T2.FK;
```